# @nestjsx/crud multiple filters doesn't work

Tags: node.js, nestjs, query-string

Im using @nestjsx/crud, and when im trying to filter a list from the ui,
the @nestjsx/crud-request generates the querystring as follows:

```
?&filter[0]=name||$cont||text
```

But the filtering only works without the indices, like this:

```
?&filter=name||$cont||text
```

What am I missing?

I did everything by the docs, didn't find anyone complaining about this

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with FastifyAdapter, solved by registering fastify-qs plugin

Comment: Add more code with example @Alon Dayan that would be helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).